# Change database value based on date (ASP)

Tags: asp-classic

I have 3 dropdown lists in a form for the user to input the date by day, month and year. How can I make that once t is the date that been input by the user, it will change the status from PUBLISH to UNPUBLISHED in the database?

Below is my codes:

Need your help. Thanks.

Comment: I recommend you reformat your code by indenting the code part by 4 spaces.

Comment: Why do you hae `<%` and `%>` on each line of code, this is not necesassary and makes your code realy unreadable. The `<%` marks the start of asp code on an html page, and the `%>` marks the end. But the block of asp code between them can include multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the `DateSerial` function to convert the separate values into date values, and use that to compare two dates.

[From the page at W3Schools:](http://www.w3schools.com/VBscript/func_dateserial.asp)

**The DateSerial function returns a Variant of subtype Date for a specified year, month, and day.**

Syntax
    DateSerial(year,month,day)

Parameter Description 
year Required. A number between 100 and 9999, or a numeric expression. Values between 0 and 99 are interpreted as the years 1900–1999. For all other year arguments, use a complete four-digit year 
month Required. Any numeric expression 
day Required. Any numeric expression

Examples
Example 1

```
document.write(DateSerial(2010,2,3))
```

The output of the code above will be:

```
2/3/2010
```

Example 2
Subtract 10 days:

```
document.write(DateSerial(2010,2,3-10))
```

The output of the code above will be:

```
1/24/2010
```